# html/javascript - Trying to validate the form

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I did a website and made a form ,and I have done the most of the validation but  I am stuck at one. what I am trying to achieve here is when the the submit button of the form is clicked, a alert message show appear on screen saying thanks'customer name' for feed back and  you chose 'radiobutton' and your comment was 'textincommentfield'.for one or another reason validation is not working. Any help would be great and thanks in advance , btw I am new to this.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/92tSw/

HTML:

```
<title> Contact</title>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="wrap">

<div id="logo">
<img class="p" src="images/logo.png" align="left">
</div>
<img class="d" src="images/title.gif" align="middle">
  <div id="menu">
<div id="menu2">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="homepage.html"  ><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html"  ><span>About Us</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="clubs.html" ><span>Clubs</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="shop.html" ><span>Shop</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html" ><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>


<form>
<fieldset>
   <legend  style="font-size:20px; padding-top:20px;">Fill in the form Below to contact Us:</legend>
   <p><label for="full name">Full Name:</label>
   <input id="full name" type="text" size="40" name="customername" placeholder="Type first and last name" autofocus/></p>


 <p><label for="Address">Address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Address Line 1" size="42%">

<input type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Address Line 2" size="42%">

<p><label for="Address">&nbsp;</label>
 <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City/Town" size="20%">
<input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Post Code" size="20%"></p>

   <p><label for="Telephone No.">Telephone Number:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Telephone No." maxlenght="12"placeholder=" Enter Telephone No." size="42%"></p>

 <p><label for="email">Email:</label>
 <input name="email" type="email" size="25" placeholder="youremail@you.com"  /></p>





<legend style="font-size:20px;" >Comments</legend>
 <p><label  for="quantity"> How great is the website?Choose one<em>*</em> :</label>

   <input type="radio"    name="myRadio"    value="VG" >Very Great &nbsp;
   <input type="radio"    name="myRadio"    value="G"  >Great&nbsp;
   <input type="radio"    name="myRadio"    value="NVG">Not Very Great&nbsp;
   <input type="radio"    name="myRadio"    value="U"  >Useless
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<p><label for="comment">Your Message:</label>

<textarea cols="35" rows="5" name="comments"  Placeholder="eg. please knock on the dooor, ring the bell etc." >


 </textarea></p>

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input type="checkbox" name="Terms and Condition"value="Terms and Condition" required> Accept Terms and Condition<br>
<input id="bor" type="reset" value="Reset">
<input id="chor" type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" onclick="getMyForm(this.form)" >
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
form{ padding-top:100px; color:White;}
fieldset { background-color:#980000   ; margin: 1%;}
label { float:left; width:20%; text-align:right;}
legend{font-weight:bold;}

 .foot {
padding-top:.75pt;
padding-bottom:.75pt;
padding-right:auto;
padding-left:auto;
width:100%;
}
```

JS:

```
function getMyForm(frm)
{
var myinfo = getRadioValue(frm.myRadio);
var customername = document.getElementById("customer").value;
   var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;


alert("Dear"+ customername + ",Thank you very much for your feedback.You have rated our site as" + myinfo +"your comment was Very informative website."+ comment +".");
}

function getRadioValue(radioArray){
    var i;
for (i = 0; i < radioArray.length; i++){
if (radioArray[i].checked) return radioArray[i].value;}
return "";
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/92tSw/ - here is the code

Comment: why don't you edit your original post and add the fiddle in there...?

Comment: @webeno do you mean just post the link there?

Comment: You can post the blocks of code into the question then highlight it and click the {} button to format it. Better to have the code actually in the post rather than somewhere else.

Comment: click edit and add it below ;) in the mean time, your issue probably (or partially) comes from the fact that you use `getElementById` but your input elements don't have an `id` attribute.

Comment: @jwatts1980 yes I will do that in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be better to have the event on the `form`

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return getMyForm(this)">
```

To prevent the form from actually submitting, you have to `return false;` from the javascript method.

To submit the form programmatically in JS

```
frm.submit();
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
```

Then `return true;` from the function under the right conditions to allow the submit to complete.

(I noticed you didn't include the `action` and `method` attributes on the `form`. I assumed this was just for the example.)

Comment: you need the return in inline attribute.  onsubmit="return getMyForm(this)"

Comment: @jwatts1980 I did put <form id="form1" onsubmit="return getMyForm(this)"> in form part and document.getElementById("form1").submit(); in the script part it , unfortunately it doesnt work.

Comment: @progysm I tried your version but when i click on submit , the alert message doesn't display which should be "Dear"+ customername + ",Thank you very much for your feedback.You have rated our site as" + myinfo +"your comment was Very informative website."+ comment +"."

Comment: @progysm would you know what's the issue why the message is not displaying?

Comment: if your form, you don't have a id="customername" and a id="comment", you have name="customername" and name="comments". This create an error, stop the code from working correctly and submit the form

Comment: @progysm Thanks dude your are life saver. I would like to answer one more thing  if you want to answer, i have a shopping page with products on it, if i want to add up the totals how would i do it.

Comment: the total? like the sum of each items price*quantity? you need a loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/92tSw/2/

Use JQuery if you are new to javascript.. its much more comfortable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yourmockform").submit(function(e) {
        var customername = $(this).find('#fullname').val();
        var comment = $(this).find('#comment').val();
        var myinfo = $(this).find('[name="myRadio"]:checked').attr('value');

        alert("Dear"+ customername + ",Thank you very much for your feedback.You have rated our site as" + myinfo +"your comment was Very informative website."+ comment +".");

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: if you prefere the complicated way =) you can do the same thing with plain egmascript like document.getElementById("formid").addEventListener("submit", callback, false); (remember, older ie doesnt understand addEventListener, so you have to do double checking etc.)